# How to add parentheses around every Regex match in jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to add parentheses or "<>" around every match in the regex, I already got all the regex sentences ready. For example:

Input:

```
int a = 0;
```

Output:

```
<int><a><=><0>
```

There's one more thing, what I'm doing is a "translator" it needs to read an arithmetic count in C and generate its tokens flow. So, for example, the "=" will `<assign_op>` and the ";" will be `<end_of_statement>`.
The sentence above would be written as:
`<int><a><assign_op><0>`

Here's the code I've been working on:

```
function translate() {
var input = 'int a = 0;' +
    '\nint b = 5;' +
    '\nint a = b + 5;' +
    '\nint c = a1 / 1;' +
    '\ndouble a = 1;' +
    '\nfloat a = 0;' +
    '\na = 0;' +
    '\nfloat a = b + 1;' +
    '\na = (b - c) * 5;';


var regex3 = new RegExp(/(((int|long int|double|long double|float)+\s*([a-zA-Z_]+\d*)*|([a-zA-Z_]+\d*))\s*=\s*(([a-zA-Z_]*|[a-zA-Z_]+\d*)*|\d*|\d+\.\d+);)|(((int|long int|double|long double|float)+\s*([a-zA-Z_]+\d*)*|([a-zA-Z_]+\d*))\s*=(\s*\(*(([a-zA-Z_]*|[a-zA-Z_]+\d*)*|\d*|\d+\.\d+)\)*\s*[+\-/*%]\s*\(*(([a-zA-Z_]*|[a-zA-Z_]+\d*)*|\d*|\d+\.\d+)\)*)*\s*;)/g);

var text = input.match(regex3);
var varTypes = ['int', 'double', 'float', 'long int', 'long double'];
var output = '';

text.forEach(line => {
    varTypes.forEach(type => {
        if (line.match(type))
            line = line.replace(type, '<' + type + '>');

    });
    if (line.match(/=/g)) {
        line = line.replace(/=/g, '<assign_op>')
    }
    if (line.match(/;/g)) {
        line = line.replace(/;/g, '<end_of_statement>');
    }
    if (line.match(/\(/g)) {
        line = line.replace(/\(/g, '<open_parenthesis>')
    }
    if (line.match(/\)/g)) {
        line = line.replace(/\)/g, '<close_parenthesis>')
    }
    if (line.match(/[+\-*/%]/g)) {
        line = line.replace(/[+\-*/%]/g, '<operator>')
    }
    if (line.match(/\+{2}/g)) {
        line = line.replace(/\+{2}/g, '<operator>')
    }
    output += line + '\n';
});

console.log(output);
```

}

Oh, sorry if I had many English writing mistakes, not an English native speaker :)

Comment: I like regex, but when it gets too complicated that it's unreadable it might be time to try a different tack.  Since each fragment in the input variable is structured more or less the same, maybe try using substring to divide the strings into left and right parts.  Everything in the right except the semicolon can be put into braces while you can simply replace the semicolon.  In the left part, you can check to see if it begins with the type and replace that bit.  What remains in the left part can be put in it's own set of braces.  Let me know if you don't follow and I'll post an example.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on your complex string manipulation problem quite long...

I came with a *"dictionary"* idea make replacements management easier. And I used the spaces to target the string elements to wrap with `<` and `>`.

Have a look at the comments within the code. [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/BEPmbY)

```js
var input = 
    'int a = 0;' +
    '\nint b = 5;' +
    '\nint a = b + 5;' +
    '\nint c = a1 / 1;' +
    '\ndouble a = 1;' +
    '\nfloat a = 0;' +
    '\na = 0;' +
    '\nfloat a = b + 1;' +
    '\na = (b - c) * 5;' +
    '\nlong int = (w - x) * 7;' + // Added to test the two words types
    '\nlong double = (x - w) * 7;';   // Added to test the two words types

var dictionary = [
  {
    target: "long int",
    replacement: "long|int" // | to ensure keeping that space, will be restored later
  },
  {
    target: "long double",
    replacement: "long|double" // | to ensure keeping that space, will be restored later
  },

  {
    target: /=/g,
    replacement: "assign_op"
  },
  {
    target: /;/g,
    replacement: "end_of_statement"
  },
  {
    target: /\(/g,
    replacement: "open_parenthesis"
  },
  {
    target: /\)/g,
    replacement: "close_parenthesis"
  },
  {
    target: /[+\-*/%]/g,
    replacement: "operator"
  },
  {
    target: /\+{2}/g,
    replacement: "operator"
  }
];


function translate(input) {

  //console.log(input);

  // Your unchanged regex
  var regex3 = new RegExp(/(((int|long int|double|long double|float)+\s*([a-zA-Z_]+\d*)*|([a-zA-Z_]+\d*))\s*=\s*(([a-zA-Z_]*|[a-zA-Z_]+\d*)*|\d*|\d+\.\d+);)|(((int|long int|double|long double|float)+\s*([a-zA-Z_]+\d*)*|([a-zA-Z_]+\d*))\s*=(\s*\(*(([a-zA-Z_]*|[a-zA-Z_]+\d*)*|\d*|\d+\.\d+)\)*\s*[+\-/*%]\s*\(*(([a-zA-Z_]*|[a-zA-Z_]+\d*)*|\d*|\d+\.\d+)\)*)*\s*;)/g);

  // An array of lines created by the use of your regex
  var lines_array = input.match(regex3);
  //console.log(lines_array);

  // The result variable
  var output = '';

  // Process each lines
  lines_array.forEach(line => {

    // Use the dictionary to replace some special cases
    // It adds spaces around the replacements to ensure word separation
    dictionary.forEach(translation => {
      if (line.match(translation.target)) {
        line = line.replace(translation.target, " "+translation.replacement+" ");  // Notice the spaces
      }
    });

    // Remove double spaces
    line = line.trim().replace(/\s+/g," ");

    // Use the spaces to get a word array to add the angle brackets
    var words = line.split(" ");
    words.forEach(word => {
      output += "<"+word+">";
    });

    // Re-add the line return
    output += '\n';
  });

  // Final fixes on the whole result string
  output = output
    .replace(/\|/g, " ")  // Restore the space in the "two words types" ( was replaced by a | )
    .replace(/<</g, "<") // Remove duplicate angle brackets
    .replace(/>>/g, ">")

  console.log(output);
}

// Run the function
translate(input);
```